# How can I profile my rails app for memory allocation hotspots and navigate back up the calltree from a hotspot to my code?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, macos, memory-management

I'm tuning my rails app to reduce the number of objects created. I've been using [MemProf](https://github.com/ice799/memprof) with Ruby 1.8 MRI and a number of improvements as a result.

Now that I've tuned the bottlenecks that reside wholly within my own code, I need something more. While a count of objects created by lines of third party code is a good hint, it doesn't help me correlate my code to the object creation. Ideally I'd be able to navigate back up the calltree from a hotspot to my code.

Are there better tool out there? I've looked at [ruby-prof](http://ruby-prof.rubyforge.org/), and I'm using REE in production.

[Ruby Memory Validator](http://www.softwareverify.com/ruby-memory-hotspot.php) looks reasonable, but it requires a Windows OS.

What are you using to tune the object creation behaviour of your rails apps?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the profiler & generate Tree output. Then analysis on that can be done using [kcachegrind](http://kcachegrind.sourceforge.net/html/Home.html), its not ruby specific but provides excellent indepth detail.

See
[Performance Testing Rails Applications](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/performance_testing.html)